# There is a method in mysql that can INSERT data only if COUNT is equal to zero?

Tags: mysql, database

Considering a registration script, i've first to check if an email is already present into the databae.
If it's present no data have to be insert, if not, i can procede with the INSERT INTO

In any case at the end of query i've to know the result for comunicate it at the final user. Acqually i've already done some script, but it requires at least two queries. My goal is to do it with only one query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you'll want to put a unique key on the e-mail address field.  This will prevent you from inserting multiple records with the same e-mail address.

Once you've done that, you can use `INSERT IGNORE` and checked the number of affected rows returned from the query.  If it's zero, you know it was a duplicate.  If it's one, then you know it wasn't.  Alternatively, you can just use a regular `INSERT` and catch the duplicate key error generated by the database to know if it was a duplicate record or not.

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO users (email, name) VALUES (:mail, :name) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT IGNORE

After that counting the results, they are always one. How i can retrieve the number of "altered" rows after a query in PDO statement?

Comment: @Anna - Try just `INSERT IGNORE INTO..` instead of `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT IGNORE`

Comment: So, $sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO users (email, name) VALUES (:mail, :name) . And after that what i should do (i remember to you that i need to know if the record has been inserted or not)? There is a method to retrive che result of the queery operation?

Comment: @Anna - Yup, have a look at this:  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: and what if in addition to the number of affected rows, i need to retrieve some values from database? For exemple, if the unique key (mail) exists, i need to retrieve the relative "user name" column data. Is it possibile?

Comment: @Anna - not in a single query, no.